# In flutter on tap get other user uid how can I?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to making a chat app like WhatsApp. I have created an admin screen. In the admin screen, if a user upload a paymentImage, then admin will allow him/her to chat.

I am facing issue on approved button, because I want to delete the Key of PaymentImage - so that the user can reupload it after some period of time or approval cancel and on approve button.

I also give him/her permission to continue chat how can I

**User admin screen**

```
InkWell(
      onTap: () {
         if(snapshot.data!.docs[index]['Uid']==FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid){
                           Get.snackbar("It's You", 'This is your profile ');
                         }
                         else{
                           Get.to(() =>

                           userDataAdminScreen(
                            Profile: snapshot.data!
                                .docs[index]['PaymentImage'], 
                            name: snapshot.data!
                                .docs[index]['Full Name'],
                            age: snapshot.data!
                                .docs[index]['Age'], 
                            cast: snapshot.data!
                                .docs[index]['Caste'], 
                            city: snapshot.data!
                                .docs[index]['City'],
                            father: snapshot.data!
                                .docs[index]['Father Name'],
                            m_status: snapshot.data!
                                .docs[index]['Marriage Status'],
                            userID: snapshot.data!
                                .docs[index]['Uid'], 
                                snapshot: snapshot.data!,
                                )

                         }
      },
      child: containter()
```

**Approved Button Screen**

```
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('UserDetails').get();
                               if (querySnapshot.docs.isNotEmpty) {
                                var tappedUserDocument = querySnapshot.docs[0];
                                String tappedUserUid = tappedUserDocument.id;
                                String targetUserId = tappedUserUid;
                                // "target_user_id";
                                DocumentReference targetUserDoc FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('UserDetails').doc(targetUserId);
                                await targetUserDoc.update({
                            FieldPath(['PaymentImage']):
                                FieldValue.delete(),
                          }).then((value) => Navigator.pop(context));
                                // print('Tapped User UID: $tappedUserUid');
                                Get.snackbar('Approved', 'Sucessfully');
                               }else{
                                print('No users found in the database');
                               }
```

}